# Can the `administered by` be replaced with `depend on` in the bellow scenario?

Tags: phrases

From the bellow link:

https://github.com/openstack/docs-specs/blob/master/specs/pike/admin-guide-repos.rst

> The growth of the number of OpenStack projects that are administered by an operator base continues to grow.

Can the `administered by` be replaced with `depend on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two have different connotations.

`administered by` means that they are maintained by that operator base. This is about management of issues, pull requests, and general 'housekeeping'.

`depend on` has a stronger meaning. It implies that, if that operator base were to fail, the project would also fail.

You can think of it like the difference between a plane being `administered by` cleaning and engineering crews, which make sure it is is working order for each flight, vs being `dependent on` it's wings to keep it in the air. Both are needed for it to function as you expect, but only one causes catastrophic failure without a lot of effort to fix the problem.

In the context of software management, it seems that an `operator base` is an entity that maintains the project, but can be changed to someone else if needed. Therefore, it would probably be wrong to say it depends on this operator base.